# RxJava: observable that contains an asynchronous call

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to understand RxJava and running into the following situation.

Consider the following method that returns an observable which calls `NsdManager.registerService`. The registerService method needs a listener which is called when registration succeeded (or failed).

```
public Observable<Boolean> registerService() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
            nsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, registrationListener);

            // how to proceed?
        }
    });
}
```

The observer can provide a notification only after the listener has been called, but the listener is called asynchronously.

How can I do this with RxJava?

---

I came up with the following, using a BehaviorSubject. Don't know if it is the best solution, but it works.

```
private BehaviorSubject<Boolean> registrationSubject;

public Observable<Boolean> registerService() {
    registrationSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();

    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
            NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo  = new NsdServiceInfo();
            serviceInfo.setServiceName(serviceName);
            serviceInfo.setServiceType(NSD_SERVICE_TYPE);
            serviceInfo.setPort(serverSocket.getLocalPort());

            nsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, registrationListener);
        }
    }).subscribe(registrationSubject);

    return registrationSubject;
}

private NsdManager.RegistrationListener registrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
        registrationSubject.onNext(false);
        registrationSubject.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
        registrationSubject.onNext(true);
        registrationSubject.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) { }

    @Override
    public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to avoid the use of Subjects whenever possible.
In your solution you only use the subject to call `onNext` and `onCompleted`. However, within the `Observable.create()` method you already have access to the `subscriber` on which you can call these methods. In other words, you can wrap the complete setup of your event handler inside the `Observable.create()` method.

```
public Observable<Boolean> registerService() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
            NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo  = new NsdServiceInfo();
            serviceInfo.setServiceName(serviceName);
            serviceInfo.setServiceType(NSD_SERVICE_TYPE);
            serviceInfo.setPort(serverSocket.getLocalPort());

            nsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, 
                new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onNext(false);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onNext(true);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {}
                }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the listener implementation call:

```
subscriber.onNext(result) 
subscriber.onComplete()
```

The `result` is a `boolean` passed to the listener.

Comment: You may also want to check that the passed subscriber is still subscribed before calling to the external service `if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) { subscriber.onNext(nsdManager.register...); subscriber.onComplete(); }`